# Jackcess -- How to change Column Name?

Tags: java, jackcess

I have a Jackcess table and everything is working just fine. BUT I can't find anything on how to change a column name in the Jackcess table.

The reason I want to change the column name is that I have a ResultSet which is converted to Microsoft Access using Jackcess. a column is named "RELATION" but when Jackcess converts it, the name is changed to "xRelation". it must be some kind of Blacklisted word...

I want to change the column name back to "RELATION" and changing "RELATION" itself to something else is not an option.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackcess cannot alter the structure of the table after it has been created. So, if you want that column to be named `Relation` instead of `xRelation` you will probably need to

- explicitly create the table first (e.g., using `TableBuilder`) with `Relation` as the column name, and then
- use `ImportUtil.importResultSet` to import into the table you created:

```java
ImportUtil.importResultSet(rs, db, "ExistingTable", new SimpleImportFilter(), true);
```

That form of [importResultSet](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/ImportUtil.html#importResultSet(java.sql.ResultSet,%20com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database,%20java.lang.String,%20com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.util.ImportFilter,%20boolean)) will import into an existing table instead of creating a new one.